# How to Evaluate $ \int e^{\sin\theta} \cos\theta \ d\theta \ $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am new to integration, I want to evaluate

$$ \int e^{\sin\theta} \cos\theta \ d\theta \ $$

I didn't know much methods, such as substitution, etc. So I want a simple way.

Edit: What I done:

Since, $ e^{sin\theta} $ is a number raised to exponent, I wrote

$$ e^{\sin\theta} \int \cos\theta \ d\theta \ $$

Which gives,

$$ e^{\sin\theta} sin\theta + C \ $$
Where C is the constant of integration.

(I also need to know why I was wrong)

Comment: As I had multiplication in the middle, I was having no idea what to do

Comment: The simplest possible way is a substitution. Hint: $x=\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Then this is a good opportunity to learn about substitutions! Try $x=\sin\theta$. What is then $dx$? Mind you, this is very likely a duplicate or a near duplicate. Did you search the site?

Comment: Then it will become $ e^x × cos\theta $ but see I don't know how to deal with multiplication in the middle

Comment: If $\sin(\theta)=x$, then $\cos(\theta)\text{d}\theta=\text{d}x$. Can you continue?

Comment: You have to compute $dx$ and substitute $d\theta$

Comment: @RaviPrakash, this is how you do substitution. Given the integrand (let's say it is a function of $x$) you define part of it as $u=f(x)$ and then compute $\text{d}u=f'(x)\text{d}x$ and then substitute the relevant expressions. Try to evaluate $$\int \frac{x}{x^2+1}\text{d}x$$

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks a lot

Comment: @Math_QED is this still off topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since you do not know much about integration techiques, as you stated, you can see, from the chain rule, that:
$$(e^{\sin\theta})'=e^{\sin\theta}(\sin\theta)'=e^{\sin\theta}\cos\theta$$
So, it is immediate that:
$$\int e^{\sin\theta}\cos\theta d\theta=\int(e^{\sin\theta})'d\theta=e^{\sin\theta}+c\mbox{, $c\in\mathbb{R}$}$$

Otherwise, you can make the substitution:
$$u=\sin\theta$$
So
$$du=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin\theta)d\theta=\cos\theta d\theta$$
And, finally:
$$\int e^{\sin\theta}\underbrace{\cos\theta d\theta}_{du}=\int e^udu=e^u+c\overset{u=\sin\theta}{=}e^{\sin\theta}+c,\ c\in\mathbb{R}$$

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: See the updated question and tell me why I was wrong

Comment: In general, as I get it, what you did is:
$$\int e^{\sin\theta}\cos\theta d\theta=\int e^{\sin\theta}d\theta\int\cos\theta d\theta=e^{\sin\theta}\int\cos\theta d\theta$$
which is, in general, wrong, since $\int fg\neq\int f\int g$ (think of $f(x)=g(x)=x$). $\int$ is linear but no way multiplicative! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the classical rules, you can work by trial and error.

As the derivative of an exponential is an exponential, start by studying

$$\left(e^{\sin \theta}\right)'.$$

Using the chain rule, it turns out that

$$\left(e^{\sin \theta}\right)'=\cos\theta\ e^{\sin \theta}$$

which is precisely your integrand.

Can you conclude ?

Comment: Can you add in answer - solving by classical rules?

Comment: @RaviPrakash: no, I haveal ready done more than enough.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's the reverse way i think

Answer (score 1):

let $u=\sin(\theta)$ then $du=\cos(\theta)d\theta$

$\implies \int e^{\sin\theta}\cos(\theta)d\theta$

$\implies\int e^udu$

$\implies e^u+C$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\sin\theta=p$ then $dp=\cos\theta \cdot d\theta$ So your integral  $\int e^{\sin\theta}\cdot \cos\theta\cdot d\theta$ is equivalent to $\int e^p.dp$